# Have any dataset of the forum about football?

Tags: football

I want some data like:

1. I need some data from the European Football League Forum, for example: discussing the Champions League, Premier League players, matches, etc;
2. I want to do some nlp tasks in the European Football Forum(English);
3. any format is ok, maybe json is better.

Comment: What is *bbs*? Also, 'soccer' is very broad. Do you want world wide data? In what form? Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] the question.

Comment: yeah, i will fix it

Comment: Yeah, I’m working in soccer data and I don’t know what bbs is 

Comment: Ah, “bulletin boards”